# Bash - Grab the output and put it in the particular place in the file

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, nginx

I have python script generating AWS Signature key for S3. It generates two values:

```
GZkXNl6Leat71ckcwfxGuiHxt9fnkj47F1SbVjRu/t0=
20190129/eu-west-2/s3/aws4_request
```

Both are valid for 7 days. What I want is to run that script for every five days using cron inside the Docker container, grab the output and place/replace values in the Nginx config
config:

```
  server {
    listen 80;
    aws_access_key 'AKIDEXAMPLE';
    aws_signing_key FIRST_VALUE;
    aws_key_scope SECOND_VALUE;
    aws_s3_bucket s3_bucket_name;

    location / {
    aws_sign;
      proxy_pass http://s3_bucket_name.s3.amazonaws.com;
    }
```

Then restart nginx in the container

Comment: What's the question?  Do you know how to invoke python?  Do you know how to make it write output?  Do you know how to capture that output?  Do you know how to modify the nginx config?  Do you know how to edit a script?  Combine the answers to those questions (and maybe a few more), and you're done.

Comment: Question is in subject. Python script gives these two lines in output. I need to put them into the Nginx config above.

Comment: Ah, so you just want someone to write the script for you, and you don't actually have a specific question.   I would say the only difficult part of the question is convincing cron to run every 5 days.  It gets tricky around the ends of the month, and is a lot easier if you allow yourself to use a date specifier of the form `0/5`.  But it's probably easier to avoid cron and just do `while sleep 432000; do cmd; done` where cmd is the command that performs the actions you want.

Comment: Yes, William I was asking to write it for me and you are right about cron, but it should also work with [ $((  $(( `date +%-j` - 1 )) % 5 )) == 0 ]. Sleep is another option I will try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the values are stored in `val_file`, slotting them into `nginx.conf`, this simplistic solution ought to do -

```
$: cat script
#! /bin/env bash
{ read -r val1    # read the first line
  read -r val2    # read the second line
  sed -i "s!FIRST_VALUE!$val1!;
          s!SECOND_VALUE!$val2!;
  " nginx.conf
} < val_file

$: script
$: cat nginx.conf
  server {
    listen 80;
    aws_access_key 'AKIDEXAMPLE';
    aws_signing_key GZkXNl6Leat71ckcwfxGuiHxt9fnkj47F1SbVjRu/t0=;
    aws_key_scope 20190129/eu-west-2/s3/aws4_request;
    aws_s3_bucket s3_bucket_name;

    location / {
    aws_sign;
      proxy_pass http://s3_bucket_name.s3.amazonaws.com;
    }
```

The curlies make the single input supply both `read`s. Then it's just a `sed`, using `!`'s because you have standard forward slashes in your data.  Double quotes on the `sed` to allow embedded vars - not ideal, but seems ok here.

Comment: That worked, thank you. However I found that I will need to run that with cron where the values in nginx.conf will contain previous (expired) Signature keys. So I will try to replace values after: aws_signing_key and before ";"

Comment: then try `sed -i 's! aws_signing_key .*; *$! aws_signing_key '$val1';!;
           s! aws_key_scope .*; *$! aws_key_scope '$val2';!;' nginx.conf` :)
`